# Attaching AJAX to Drupal Forms API Date Field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am developing a Drupal form which includes a Date field.

I have a number of AJAX callbacks on this form that work well, but now I want to change some form elements depending on the age of the user, so when the date changes, other fields get replaced. Unfortunately, the "#ajax" element is not available on date fields (presumably because the field has three selects, rather than a single select).

Is there another way I can implement an AJAX callback?

I'm considering splitting the date field into 3 selects, which could each have an AJAX element, but that would lose all the benefits of the date field, so I don't want to unless I have to.

Thanks for your help,

James

Comment: date_popup (install Date module) has this.

Comment: The solution that worked for me was to put a hidden button on the form and attach the #ajax element to that. I then attached some JavaScript to the date control drop-downs to make them click the button.